# Integrating SAML2 App in ASP.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml-2.0

I have ASP.net application that is working in SSO environment(ADFS2), now I need to integrate third party cloud based application which requires SAML assertion with facilityid, audienceid, issuer and few specific values. I'm looking for example (ASP.net/C# code) or helpful link in this regard.
I did looked around and most of example were configuring SSO, which is not what I'm looking for.

Please help.

Comment: If you're not looking for SSO, then what _are_ you looking for exactly? Can you define what you mean by "integrate" precisely? What features/behaviours do you need? The whole point of SAML to enable SSO, basically.

Comment: I have good experience with this: https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2

Comment: Here is what I mean by integration - today my Application (App1) is invoking third party app (App2) with direct url, but new version of App2 needs SAML2 assertion token with facilityid, audienceid, issuer and few specific values. How do I pass these from ASP.net application?

Comment: That is the same as SSO, is it not? If not, then what exactly do you expect those values to do? What does the "direct URL" do currently?